# mySQL - Using two JOINs in one query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to use two JOIN statements in one query,

```
$sqlsorgu = mysql_query("SELECT *, COUNT(*), AVG(clicks), AVG(scrolls), AVG(spent)
FROM track where referid='".$memberr."' GROUP BY referer ORDER BY id desc limit 15 
JOIN
(
   select id, country, num, num*100/total pct 
   from (SELECT id,country, count(*) as num 
   FROM track GROUP BY country 
   ORDER BY num desc limit 5) x 
   join (select count(*) total from track) y
) tc on t.id = tc.id") or die(mysql_error());
```

but I am getting this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN ( select id, country, num, num*100/total pct from (SELECT id,country' at line 1

What is the correct way to use it ?

Comment: The join goes in the `from` clause.  Not after the `order by`.  Move everything from the `where` after the `join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP BY/ WHERE/ Order by come after join statements. Try reording like:

```
"SELECT *, COUNT(*), AVG(clicks), AVG(scrolls), AVG(spent)
FROM track t
JOIN
(
   select id, country, num, num*100/total pct 
   from (SELECT id,country, count(*) as num 
   FROM track GROUP BY country 
   ORDER BY num desc limit 5) x 
   join (select count(*) total from track) y
) tc on t.id = tc.id
where referid='".$memberr."' 
GROUP BY referer 
ORDER BY tc.id desc limit 15
```

Comment: you need to define what t is (after track) i edited my answer. Otherwise it won't know what to join on

Comment: Gotcha. But now it says  Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous.

Comment: use t.id or tc.id (according to your needs). It is always good practice to include the table name when joins are used to clarify where the data is being pulled from..

Comment: Use t.id or tc.id instead of what ? Could you please edit answer if it's possible ? thanks!

Comment: in the order by id, if t and tc both have the id column it will be ambiguous which one to use. I edited the answer using tc.id